# Overpass install fails with std::bad_alloc

Tags: installation, overpass-api

I'm following the official HOWTO here: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Installation I get to the database import step. I have osm.bz2 dumps downloaded from Geofabrik.de.

`init_osm3s.sh` script fails with this:

`Reading XML file ...Reading XML file ...terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
./init_osm3s.sh: line 44:  8618 Broken pipe             bunzip2 < $PLANET_FILE
      8619 Aborted                 (core dumped) |  $EXEC_DIR/bin/update_database --db-dir=$DB_DIR/ $META $COMPRESSION`

Google tells me that it is possibly "out of memory" exception. But that machine have 4G RAM + 4G swap on it. I tried monitoring memory usage with `top` and `free` and I see there is plenty of memory left. It gets to around 3000MB/600MB total system used/free, nothing used from the swap and then it fails.

Overpass version 0.7.52
Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: "I have osm.bz2 dumps downloaded from Geofabrik.de."

There are huge differences between different extracts. Which one did you use?

Comment: I'm using the Europe dump. What do you mean with "huge difference"? Btw, it seems my problem was really memory-related. I ran the script and now it is running with `--flush-size=1`, although it seems it will be running for very long time...

Comment: You didn't tell us, which extract you were using. Geofabrik offers a wide range of different extracts, e.g. where Andorra has 1.2MB, while Europe has 16.7GB. `--flush-size=1` is only a workaround and might cause trouble when used to update a database (rather than setting up the database for the first time). More memory would be the better option.

Comment: It is the Europe osm.bz2 dump. Whole Europe is about 25GB and it looks it might be a spoon too big for my mouth... The init script is going for 40-something hours now, and I think it has a long way to go ahead. I might have to kill it at some point...

Comment: BTW: This looks much like a cross post: http://forum.openstreetmap.org/viewtopic.php?pid=582870#p582870

Comment: Yeah, that's me, too.